# Return value homework in Python

Tags: python

> Write a function that returns the type of clothing you should wear, based on the parameter temperature. If the temperature is below -10, you will wear a parka and toque (return “parka and toque”). If the temperature is between -10 and 0, wear a toque (return “toque”). If the temperature is greater than 0 but less than 10, wear a sweater (return “sweater”). If the temperature is between 10 and 20, wear a t-shirt (return “t-shirt”). If the temperature is greater than 20, wear shorts (return “shorts”).
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> wear_the_right_thing(25) == "shorts"
>
> wear_the_right_thing(-25) == "parka and toque"
>
> wear_the_right_thing(-5) == "toque"
> ```

here is my code:

```
def wear_the_right_thing(temperature):
    if temperature < -10:
        return "parka and toque"  
    if temperature >= -10:
        return "toque"
    if temperature > -10 and temerature <= 0:
        return "sweater"
    if temperature > 10 and temperature <= 20:
        return "t-shrit"
    if temperature > 20:
        return "shorts"
```

Here is my result (not the output this just my marked):

```
Result  Actual Value    Expected Value  Notes
Fail    'toque' 'shorts'    wear_the_right_thing(25)
Fail    'toque' 't-shirt'   wear_the_right_thing(20)
Fail    'toque' 't-shirt'   wear_the_right_thing(15)
Fail    'toque' 't-shirt'   wear_the_right_thing(10)
Fail    'toque' 'sweater'   wear_the_right_thing(9)
Fail    'toque' 'sweater'   wear_the_right_thing(1)
Pass    'toque' 'toque' wear_the_right_thing(0)
Pass    'toque' 'toque' wear_the_right_thing(-10)
Pass    'parka and toque'   'parka and toque'   wear_the_right_thing(-11)
Pass    'parka and toque'   'parka and toque'   wear_the_right_thing(-30)
You passed: 40.0% of the tests
```

so i fail the test so can help me to get 100 thank you very much

Comment: i dont know why i my code and result is showing like that

Comment: the structure of your if conditions is incorrect. Start testing with one value, if you don't get the expected output, reorder/change the conditions and try again. Repeat the process until you get all test cases correct.

Comment: Think about the order of the if-statements. There are also some typos.

Comment: Use `if-elif-else`

Answer (score 0):

You have over lapping conditions.  "toque" is always reported if temperature is above -10. You also have spelling mistakes, e.g. "temperature".

```
def wear_the_right_thing(temperature):
if temperature < -10:
    return "parka and toque"  
elif temperature >= -10 and temperature <= -5:
    return "toque"
elif temperature > -10 and temperature <= 0:
    return "sweater"
elif temperature > 0 and temperature <= 20:
    return "t-shrit"
elif temperature > 20:
    return "shorts"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `and` to give multiple condition in one `if` statement.
Example
`if temperature > -10 and temperature < 0 :`
`return "toque"`

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with your conditions, try something like this

```
def wear_the_right_thing(temperature):

    if temperature < -10:
        return "parka and toque"
    elif -10 <= temperature <= -5:
        return "toque"
    elif -5 < temperature <= 0:
        return "sweater"
    elif 0 < temperature <= 20:
        return "t-shrit"
    elif temperature > 20:
        return "shorts"
```

Comment: nice if you find in wmci com science website go to text book in cs20 or cs30...it might have lots of problems and details i hope you can find something that make you happy